# Mercurial; hg log command displays huge, unorganized list of files for rev 0 inside of a cloned repository

Tags: windows-7, mercurial

I'm brand new with mercurial, but I searched the net and couldn't find any information regarding this problem.

I've got a repository on Bitbucket which I am using to work from my laptop and my desktop.
The repository originated from my laptop and on that computer the `hg log` for `rev 0` looks completely normal.

Today I cloned the repository onto my desktop for the first time, made my changes, made my commit, and pushed the changes.
For some reason on this computer, when I use the `hg log` command, or `hg log -r 0`, **I get a huge list without line breaks of all the files that were added to the repository on the original commit**.

Am I missing something here?

Thank you

Comment: That’s not right, the output of hg log should list changeset, tag, user, date and summary. It sounds like an installation problem. Can you provide the output of `hg version` and `hg showconfig`? Also, what operating system do you use and how did you install Mercurial?

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to fomat the output of hg log, as described in [Chapter 11. Customizing the output of Mercurial](http://hgbook.red-bean.com/read/customizing-the-output-of-mercurial.html):

```
hg log -r 0 --template '{desc}\nfiles: {files}\n'
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your configuration for `verbose = True`.

`hg log` doesn't list the files affected by a commit by default, but does when `verbose` is on.